# PHPUnit returning always JSON objects

Tags: php, json, phpunit

When executing php phpunit.phar I'm always getting the results in the following format:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:              The Xdebug extension is not loaded
                                No code coverage will be generated.

{
    "event": "suiteStart",
    "suite": "CodeIgniter Application Test Suite",
    "tests": 3
}{
    "event": "suiteStart",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "tests": 3
}{
    "event": "testStart",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "test": "Welcome_test::test_index"
}{
    "event": "test",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "test": "Welcome_test::test_index",
    "status": "pass",
    "time": 0.020705938339233,
    "trace": [],
    "message": "",
    "output": ""
}.{
    "event": "testStart",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "test": "Welcome_test::test_method_404"
}{
    "event": "test",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "test": "Welcome_test::test_method_404",
    "status": "pass",
    "time": 0.0022480487823486,
    "trace": [],
    "message": "",
    "output": ""
}.{
    "event": "testStart",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "test": "Welcome_test::test_APPPATH"
}{
    "event": "test",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "test": "Welcome_test::test_APPPATH",
    "status": "pass",
    "time": 0.00034213066101074,
    "trace": [],
    "message": "",
    "output": ""
}.

Time: 821 ms, Memory: 10.00Mb

OK (3 tests, 3 assertions)
```

I've been trying to use the multiple command-line options listed in https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html but none worked.

I need my results in the regular format that shows only results in the format:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. Starting test 'Welcome_test::test_index' .

Starting test 'Welcome_test::test_method_404' .

Starting test 'Welcome_test::test_APPPATH' .

Time: 1.23 seconds, Memory: 13.25Mb OK (3 tests, 3 assertions)
```

The format that shows the whole execution process in JSON is making my VisualPHPUnit to break.
My phpunit.xml is the following:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./Bootstrap.php" backupGlobals="true" colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="CodeIgniter Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="test.php">./</directory>
            <exclude>./_ci_phpunit_test/</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../controllers</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../models</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../views</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../libraries</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../helpers</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../hooks</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
    <!-- This is required for VPU to work correctly -->
    <listeners>
        <listener class="PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON"/>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Any solution/suggestion? Is this a bug or a configuration issue?

Thanks

Comment: could you share config and commands you used to run suite?

Comment: @MateuszSip what do you mean with the config? Sorry, I'm new to PHPUnit. If you mean the phpunit.xml then I just added it to the question. The command I'm using is:
php phpunit.phar
I also tried php phpunit.phar --debug but it didn't work. I'd appreciate any help since I've been stuck here for a while. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like `PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON` does that. I can't see a mention about it in `VisualPHPUnit` repository.

Comment: Seems like you're right! I've removed and executed php phpunit.phar --debug and the result was the expected. I had added PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON because I'm following a guide to use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter and it mentioned that it needed that line for VisualPHPUnit to work. Anyway, this worked at the moment, if it doesn't work with VPU then I guess I'd have to work only through the console. Thanks a lot. If you want, submit you answer and I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON` listener is responsible of that:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class="PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON"/>
</listeners>
```

If you need some help regarding `VisualPHPUnit` I can try, but it could require some details about your configuration.

Is it a tool you really need or just a nice addition?

Comment: Well, it'd be a nice addition. I'm trying to convince my supervisor to adopt TDD so giving him the options of examine results through the browser would be perfect. What other details regarding configuration would you need?